# UIView initWithFrame overwrite view height

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I have a UIView with a NIB. The view in the NIB is set to 280 x 390.

When I add the View inside another view I "something" do this

view_name *view = [view_name alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280.00, 390.00) ];

[outer_view addSubview: view];

Now in certain instances I need to make the view smaller as there is other content on the page. I tried to change the initWithFrame variables but it does not work.

How can I do this?
Cheers!

Comment: Is your 'view_name' object loading the view from a nib? I ask because you say the view is defined with a nib, but creating something with initWithFrame typically has nothing to do with a nib.

Answer (score 0):

put a uiscrollview, set its size to your desired one, and add your view as a subview to the scrollview.